# Android studio not showing project files

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Please I have been working on a flutter project on android studio, and at one point I found myself with this situation, the project files on the left is not showing, there is this loading icon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sStBp.png)

Comment: I think it's still loading your project. Pls reopen android folder in Android Studio and wait until it finishes.

Answer (score 8):

Android Studio started opening my Flutter project as an Android-only project for some reason. Deleting the `.idea` folder at the Flutter project root removes all the IDE settings. Reopening the project after that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change that Android on top Left to Project i think this will fix it

Answer (score 2):

Invalidating cache and restart will solve your problem.

1. From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches.
2. Click Invalidate and Restart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .idea file then invalidate caches/Restart. You will find the option on 'File' menu. It should solve the problem.